# Android does not display emoji icons properly? Encoding issue?

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, encoding, emoji

As in topic, looking for sollution of issue why Android does not display emoji icons properly. It shows flat line, or sporadically random number as in attached graphic.

[image]

[image]

Regards